# Prove or Disprove a Property of $f$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Let $f:[0,1]\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function, prove or give a counter-example that there exists a $c\in[0,1]$ such that $\frac{4[f(1)-f(0)]}{\pi}=(1+c^2)f'(c)$

attempt: I tried to give a proof using the mean value theorem. Since $f$ is differentiable on $[0,1]$ we have that $\exists\xi\in[0,1]$ such that

$$\begin{align}
f'(\xi)&=f(1)-f(0)
\end{align}$$

then we have that

$$\begin{align}
\frac{4[f(1)-f(0)]}{\pi}&=\frac{4f'(\xi)}{\pi}
\end{align}$$

then i defined $g(x)=(1+x^2)f'(x)-\frac{4[f(1)-f(0)]}{\pi}$, then we have that

$$\begin{align}
g(0)&=f'(0)-\frac{4[f(1)-f(0)]}{\pi}\\
g(1)&=2f'(1)-\frac{4[f(1)-f(0)]}{\pi}
\end{align}$$

but it didn't help much; How i can proove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $g(x) = \arctan(x)$. The question can be transformed to:

Is there a $c \in [0,1]$ such that 
$$ \frac{f(1) - f(0)}{g(1) - g(0)} = \frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)} = (1+c^2)f'(c).$$